# using html5 video with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to add overlay (in this case video) to my `react-leaflet` map using html5.

```
<div>
    <Map viewport={this.state.viewport} onViewportChanged={this.onViewportChanged} zoomControl={false} ref='map'>
        <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' />
    </Map>
    <div>
        <video id="samp" width="540" height="300" controls>
            <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </source>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

But leaflet keeps overriding the video. Best for me would be to keep the video outside of the leaflet (although i know that there is a video-overlay component in leaflet i would prefer not to use it)

Comment: What are the z-indexes of the final HTML elements? Do the video and the map belong to the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Stacking_context) ?

Comment: hi, solved yesterday, forgot to post answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i while i was able to do this, video was hidden behind some of the map components (not map it self), so the rendering of the vid was funny.
Setting the z-index to 1000 and position to absolute solved my problem.

```
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```